# CS0133 "The expression being assigned to 'identifier' must be constant" - what's the reason behind that?

Tags: c#, .net

With a lot of C++ background I've got used to writing the following:

```
const int count = ...; //some non-trivial stuff here
for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
   ...
}
```

and I expected that the same would work fine in C#. However...

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
const int count = buffer.Length;
```

produces *error CS0133: The expression being assigned to 'count' must be constant*.

I don't get it. Why is that invalid? `int` is a value type, isn't it? Why can't I assign a value and make the variable unchangeable this way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because `const` in C# is a lot more `const` than `const` in C++. ;)

In C#, `const` is used to denote a compile-time constant expression. It'd be similar to this C++ code:

```
enum {
  count = buffer.Length;
}
```

Because `buffer.Length` is evaluated at runtime, it is not a constant expression, and so this would produce a compile error.

C# has a `readonly` keyword which is a bit more similar to C++'s `const`. (It's still much more limited though, and there is no such thing as const-correctness in C#)

Comment: What's the limitation vs. what I'd expect from const?  And phew, not sure I followed Wikipedia's defn of "const-correctness".  Just that it uses const where appropriate?  How does readonly bork that correctness?

Comment: @ruffin: in C#, const and readonly can only be applied to class members. In C++, const doesn't mean "compile-time constant", but "will not be modified". You can have const member methods (meaning they don't modify the class they are a member of, and so, if you have a const object, you are only allowed to call const methods on it. Function parameters can be const, (again, meaning that the function being called can't modify the parameters, or call non-const member functions on it).

Comment: This allows you to create a notion of "const-correctness". That is, you can distinguish between "modifying" and "nonmodifying" functions, and detect at compile-time if you accidentally try to perform a modifying operation on a const object. You can define a class to limit the operations that can be performed on it if it is const, and if you do so consistently throughout your program, it is const-correct. Any attempt at violating "logical" constness becomes a compile-time error.

Comment: In C#, you have no way of expressing that "Function A is allowed to modify this object, but function B should access it in a read-only manner". You can expose a List<T> and *hope* that the callee doesn't modify it. Or you can expose a copy of the data, or you can use some contrived and crippled interface like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. But what you really wanted was just to define function B like this: `void B(const List<T> myList)`: a function which list and promises to treat it as const

Comment: Thanks. If I hadn't already upvoted, I obviously would now.  I was stuck in VB6 const usage-land, where you (I?) mostly just fixed strings and ints (at times, even living grouped in modules) so that nobody could accidentally change them or mistype their values.  Obviously readonly solves that usage.  Function-level parameter constant constraints (etc etc, so beyond simple not-ByRef protections) would be awesome.  Thanks for the great explanation & quick reply.

Answer (score 12):

`const` is meant to represent a compile-time constant... not just a read-only value.

You can't specify read-only but non-compile-time-constant local variables in C#, I'm afraid. Some local variables are inherently read-only - such as the iteration variable in a `foreach` loop and any variables declared in the fisrt part of a `using` statement. However, you can't create your own read-only variables.

If you use `const` within a method, that effectively replaces any *usage* of that identifier with the compile-time constant value. Personally I've rarely seen this used in real C# code.

Answer (score 6):

You can't assign a variable number to a `const`. It is a compile time constant.

From the C# reference on [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx):

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that in C#, the modifier `readonly` is only available for member variables, **not** for local variables (i.e. defined inside a method).

Microsoft probably should have been more specific in the C# reference guide:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

Comment: Local consts are allowed, as mentioned in Jon Skeet's answer.