# Is there a way to concat string with char as a const?

Tags: c#, string, char, constants

If I try

```
const char NoChar = (char)8470; //№
const char TmChar = (char)8482; //™
const string IdDisplayName = "Clements" + TmChar + ' ' + NoChar;
```

it will throw a compile error:

> The expression being assigned to '{0}' must be constant

As far as I understand, this error occurs because when a char is because the string concatenation operator (`+`) internally calls `ToString` on the concatenated object.

My question is if there is a way (unmanaged?[image: Tongue]) to do it.

I need to pass that constant as an attribute and it should be generated on client.

The uglier workaround (will see what's uglier based on your answers...) is to subclass that attribute (which is sealed, will have to make some decompilation and copy-paste work) and embedding it as a non-const will be possible.

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394899/cs0133-the-expression-being-assigned-to-identifier-must-be-constant-whats

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're allowed to specify unicode character values directly in a string via the `\u` escape. So `const string IdDisplayName = "Clements\u2122 \u2116";` should get you what you want.

Comment: What's the formula of `2122 == 8482`?

Comment: @Shimmy 2122 is the hexadecimal (base 16) representation of the decimal number 8482.

Comment: I think that your answer is in line with this statement from (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

"A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time. Therefore, the only possible values for constants of reference types are string and null. but I don't really understand what evaluated fully means, is not the concatenation in OP fully evaluated at compile time!?

Comment: probably "fully evaluated" refers to the final string, and not the pieces that will eventually become one string at runtime!? any thoughts from experts on why this makes sense are appreciated.

Comment: because when you make `"string" + ... objects to concatenate...`, it internally calls `ToString` of all those objects, then concatenates the strings strings. Now obviously `ToString` is a runtime method that can definitely be called 'const'. [Here is a demo](http://rextester.com/RLGGX69222).

Answer (score 3):

I assume that simply:

```
const string NoChar = "\x2116"; //№ - Unicode char 8470
const string TmChar = "\x2122"; //™ - Unicode char 8482
const string IdDisplayName = "Clements" + TmChar + " " + NoChar;
```

Is unacceptable?